# upgrade from jQuery 1.4.2 to 1.6.2

Tags: javascript, jquery

the latest version of [jQuery Marquee Simple](http://code.google.com/p/jq-simple-marquee/), uses jQuery 1.4.2.
but the newer version of jQuery is 1.6.2, and I use that version.

that script, doesn't work with 1.6.2 (work perfectly with 1.4.2!). And I don't know how can I upgrade that code to 1.6.2.

Can you help me?

[jquery simple marquee demo 1.4.4](http://jsfiddle.net/TjfRx/)

[jquery simple marquee demo 1.6.2](http://jsfiddle.net/TjfRx/1/)

Thanks ..

Comment: Why not downgrade to 1.4.2 for the page that requires it while the Marquee works on getting up to latest?

Comment: Have you considered not living in 1995. There's a reason why everyone hates `<marquee>`

Comment: That is so much code, for something so annoying

Comment: What's up with the downvotes? Looks like perfectly valid question to me. And btw, it is not always you who decides what features there should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of changes. Most notably the offsetHeight/offsetWidth attribute getter will return undefined instead of a number. I've modded the fiddle - don't try to use cookies in it - I don't think it will work!

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TjfRx/4/) -** this has only been tested in Chrome although the theory should carry!*

Comment: +1, nice middle fingering towards the old fashioned coders! :D Edit: I thought you created the fiddle like that, apparently the old fashioned coder was flashing one towards himself.